# Output not coming as expected for function call inside loop

Tags: c++, function, loops, pointers

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <set>
#include <list>
#include <map>
#include <cmath>
#include <queue>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include "C:\Users\HP\Documents\Dreyfus-Wagner\Dijkstra.h"

using namespace std;

#define MAX 100001
#define pir pair<int, int>
#define pbd(x) push_back(x)

using namespace std;
#define MAX 100001
#define pir pair<int, int>
#define pbd(x) push_back(x)

struct Out
{
    int *p;
};
vector<pir> Graph[MAX];

int main()
{
    int nodes1, edges1, starting1;
    // create graph
    cout << "Enter the number of vertices and edges: ";
    cin >> nodes1 >> edges1;
    cout << "Enter the edges with weigth: <source> <destination> <weigth>: \n";
    int u1, v1, w1;
    struct Out output[nodes1];
    int adjMatrix[nodes1][nodes1];
    for (int i = 0; i < edges1; i++)
    {
        cin >> u1 >> v1 >> w1;
        Graph[u1].pbd(pir(v1, w1));
        Graph[v1].pbd(pir(u1, w1)); // for undirected
    }
    cout << "Enter the source node: ";
    cin >> starting1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= nodes1; i++)
    {
        output[i].p = Djiktra(nodes1, edges1, i, Graph);
    }

    for (int j = 1; j <= nodes1; j++)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= nodes1; i++)
        {
            cout << "*(p + " << i << ") : ";
            cout << *(output[j].p + i) << endl;
            ;
        }

        cout << " " << endl;
    }
}
```

[image: Output from the above code. The values that are coming are incorrect]

If we call the single instance of function it gives correct output.
Note : Djiktra function is stored in another file that is referred in header. The idea is that to find shortest lengths of elements per node

Could anyone explain why the output is incorrect when called inside for loop?

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Your `output` array has `nodes1` size, but you are indexing with `nodes1`. Valid indexes are 0 to `nodes1 - 1`.